# Query Regarding Transitivity of a Set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am having issues with understanding that given a set $A[{1,2,3}]$ why a relation set $[{(1,1),(2,2),(3,3)}]$ would be transitive?

Comment: Do you know the definition of transitivity? According to that definition, how can the relation _not_ be transitive? Please share your reasoning; otherwise it will be a pure guessing game to figure out what your misunderstanding is.

Comment: Could you explain to me why this is transitive using the definition, I am new to the topic and am somewhat confused by this example.

Comment: I'm afraid it would be a waste of time to attempt that as long as you insist on keeping it a secret what your actual problem is. Presumably you have a textbook that gives you a definition and tries to tell you how it works; _at the very least_ you need to reproduce your definition and write what thoughts you have when trying to apply that definition to the concrete example here. Unless and until you provide some actual information, it will be impossible to help you.

Comment: My understanding is that $(a,b)$ ,$(b,c)$ must be present within it in order to say $(a,c)$ which they are not.

Comment: But rather we have $(a,a)$ , $(b,b)$ and $(c,c)$

Comment: What are $a$, $b$, and $c$ when you say $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$? And why do you think $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ "must be present"? I suspect your definition  is something like "if $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are present, then $(a,c)$ must also be present" -- though I cannot know for sure since you are obstinately refusing to tell me the definition you're working with! -- but in that case what it says is that $(a,c)$ must be present, but that requirement only applies WHEN $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ are.

Comment: Give me a few mins and I will explain on my PC.

Comment: The _empty relation_ is transitive. And here, even if you want to have an $a$, $b$ and $c$ such that your relation contains $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ -- but I will bet anything that your secret definition of "transitive" does not require that anyway! -- you can easily get that by setting $a=2$, $b=2$, and $c=2$, for example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68777/discussion-between-jayvb-and-henning-makholm).

Answer (score 0):

Assume x <= y and y <= z.  Thus x = y and y = z.
So x = z, x <= z.

The tricky part is to see that equality, the order <=     of this problem, is an order, a trivial order.

That order has the unusual property of being both
symmetric and antisymmetric.

Exercise.  For a given set, show that equality is the
only order that is both  symmetric and antisymmetric.